# Turning an exception into an IObservable exception

Tags: exception, system.reactive

I have the following code:

```
var s = Observable
    .StartAsync(tnk => CERNWebAccess.GetWebResponse(reqUri))
    .SelectMany(resp => Observable.StartAsync(tkn => resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()))
    .Select(ParseToMD);
```

The ParseToMD is pretty simple:

```
private static IDocumentMetadata ParseToMD(string marc21XML)
{
    return MARC21Parser.ParseForMetadata(marc21XML);
}
```

Unfortunately, it is quite legal for the ParseForMetadata to throw an exception. I'd very much like to be able to use the normal Rx techniques to deal with the exception. For example:

```
var goodOrEmpty = s.Catch(Observable.Empty<Tuple<PaperStub, PaperFullInfo>>());
```

How can I properly protect that Select call so exceptions are correctly turned into IObservable On Error? I'm also going to need to do it for the others (StartAsync).

Comment: You should get an OnError with that code as is. Are you not?

Comment: Event when I have that ".Catch" I get an unhandled exception.

Comment: You are right, there is something more going on with this code. I tried to isolate it in a minimal test and Catch worked as expected. So there is something else going on that I'm missing. More when I work it out. Thanks!

Comment: Argh. Turns out this has something to do with the debugger. When I run under the debugger I sometimes catch this exception (but not always) and it declares it "unhandled". However, when I actually let things run, the code continues as if the .Catch worked properly. So perhaps the debugger doesn't understand how Rx is doing its exception handling?

Comment: I often get tricked into thinking an exception is unhandled when I enabled "break on thrown exceptions". Could that be the case here?

Comment: Ok. You got it Christopher. Actually, and a seemingly new behavior I've not seen before: in the Output window there is now a printout (I'm using VS2013, with update 1 applied) in red that says "first chance exception thrown" Those two together had me confused. If you write up your comment as an answer I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern I follow is a little different from the standard way of dealing with exceptions. Just because a select throws an exception doesn't necessarily mean the subscription is bad.  The next event might be fine.

Note that in RX, when OnError is triggered it means the subscription **must** be terminated.

What I do is wrap my selects in a monadic Exceptional type to do the following

```
Exceptional<IDocumentMetadata> s = Observable
    .StartAsync(tnk => CERNWebAccess.GetWebResponse(reqUri))
    .SelectMany(resp => Observable.StartAsync(tkn => resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()))
    .SelectExceptional(ParseToMD);
```

If you just want to skip the bad ones

```
    s.SelectMany(s=>s)
```

or you can project it like

```
    var Exceptional<ProcessedDocumentType> = 
        s.Select(document => ProcessDocument(document))
```

If you need to extract the exception from the Exceptional type you can do this with properties

```
bool HasException
Exception Exception
```

To get the value you can access the property

```
T Value
```

However you should use Select and SelectMany if you are just operating on the good values and don't need the exceptions.

My implementation was based on

[Exception or Either monad in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772727/exception-or-either-monad-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Ah, very nice, thanks. I effectively do this because my s.Catch() expression sits inside a SelectMany: it just means that this particular search string had a problem, not that the next search string the user enters has a problem. However, my way is "raw" and yours is nice an encapsulated and therefore easy to reuse!

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, I have to wonder if you are seeing the effect of using `StartAsync` rather than `FromAsync`. These methods differ in one important detail; the former runs once as soon as it is evaluated - i.e. it runs exactly once regardless of and before any number of subscribers. If there are no subscribers and it throws you will have an unobserved exception. Contrast with `FromAsync` which is called per subscriber on subscription.

Comment: ooo interesting thought.

Comment: Yeah - and I think this might be one of those gnarly cases where .NET 4.0 is different than .NET 4.5.x. I've not tested it on .NET 4.0 - but Rx 2.2 on .NET 4.5 just shows the first chance exception in the output (however wrong that seems to be, exceptions shouldn't just disappear!)

Comment: Ah! Thanks!! I'd not appreciated this. I now note (blush) that in my notes I had something about understanding the difference between these two, but hadn't gotten to it. I've been using them without really thinking about them - so I'd be willing to bet there are other as-yet-undiscovered bugs due to this in my code. Thanks!!